I cannot make a POST request with the Ktor library in Kotlin
I have a KMM library project in Kotlin, and I want to write a sendEvent function. The purpose of the function is to use an SSLPinner class to make a request to the server with the pinned HTTP client it obtains, and log the response to the terminal. Here is my code:
SSLPinner:
actual class SSLPinner actual constructor(
    actual val isEnabled: Boolean
) {
    actual fun getPinnedClient(domainUrl: String, certificate: String): HttpClient {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return HttpClient(OkHttp)
        }

        val url = domainUrl.split("://").getOrNull(1) ?: domainUrl
        val domainPort = url.split("/").first()
        val domain = domainPort.split(":").first()

        return try {
            HttpClient(OkHttp) {
                engine {
                    preconfigured = getOkHttpClientWithPinner(domain, certificate)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw Exception(e.message)
        }
    }

    private fun getOkHttpClientWithPinner(domain: String, certificate: String): OkHttpClient {
        return try {
            val pins = arrayOf(certificate)
            val certificatePinner = CertificatePinner.Builder()
                .add(domain, *pins)
                .build()

            OkHttpClient.Builder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build()
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Failed to create CertificatePinner: ${e.message}", e)
        }
    }
}

SendEvent:
class Sumer private constructor() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var apiKey: String
        private lateinit var apiUrl: String
        private lateinit var sslCertPin: String
        private lateinit var sslPinner: SSLPinner
        private lateinit var events: List<String>

        private var userID: String? = null

        fun initialize(apiKey: String, apiUrl: String, sslCertPin: String, isSSLPinningEnabled: Boolean, events: List<String> = emptyList()) {
            this.apiKey = apiKey
            this.apiUrl = apiUrl
            this.sslCertPin = sslCertPin
            this.sslPinner = SSLPinner(isSSLPinningEnabled)
            this.events = events
        }

        @OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
        private suspend fun sendEvent(eventName: String, properties: Map<String, Any>) {
            val client = sslPinner.getPinnedClient(apiUrl, sslCertPin)
            try {
                val jsonBody = buildJsonObject {
                    put("event_name", JsonPrimitive(eventName))
                    put("properties", buildJsonObject {
                        properties.forEach { (key, value) ->
                            put(key, JsonPrimitive(value.toString()))
                        }
                    })
                }.toString()

                val response = client.post {
                    url(apiUrl)
                    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                    header("Authorization", "Bearer $apiKey")
                    body = jsonBody
                }
                println("Response: $response")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error sending event: ${e.message}")
            } finally {
                client.close()
            }
        }

        fun track(eventName: String, properties: Map<String, Any>) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val eventProperties = properties.toMutableMap()
                userID?.let {
                    eventProperties["userID"] = it
                }
                sendEvent(eventName, eventProperties)
            }
        }

    }
}

I tried the above code, but neither the response nor any errors are printed to the terminal, and no request is sent to the server-side.

Does it print out anything for the println("Response:... line? If it doesn't do you know where the execution is actually going?
